# How to implement E-mail success callback for send mail method for phonegap(android/iphone)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, email, cordova

I am working on one application which work on Android and IOS. I am using EmailComposer-phonegap-plugin Phonegap EmailComposer plugin to send email.

The application is working fine except for that I am not able to get return values such as 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. On getting those return values I want to perform other task including email-sent or email-fail.

I have looked at many posts but I cannot find a proper solution.

I am using the Email Composer plugin https://github.com/GalCohen/EmailComposer-phonegap-plugin.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: function sendMail() 
{
 var ops = {
     callback:function(result){console.log(result);},// result is call back from plugin 0/1/2 (which i am not getting from plugin)
     subject: "Look at this photo",
     body: "Take a look at this",
     toRecipients: ["test@maymail.com"],
     ccRecipients: [],
     bccRecipients: [],
     isHTML: true,
     attachments: []
       }
   window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(ops.callback, ops.subject, ops.body, ops.toRecipients, ops.ccRecipients, ops.bccRecipients, ops.isHTML, ops.attachments);
}

Comment: post it on the question, not as a comment. But anyways, read CommonsWare's answer, the return values won't work on android, just on iOS

Answer (score 1):

That will not be possible, at least for Android. The request to send an email via `Intent` (as is used by the pluging) is asynchronous, and you do not find out what the user did with the email message in any case.

Comment: On iOS it's possible, but I suppose he is talking about android